# Typo3: How to make sorting of extension records visible in frontend?

Tags: typo3

If records are sortable in backend, this sortation isn't implicitly respected in the frontend.
What needs to be set, to get the `$this->extensionRepository->findAll()` method return the records in the sorted order? (where "extension" is the name of the extesion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines to `ExtensionRepository.php` (while "Extension" is your extension name):

```
protected $defaultOrderings = array(
    'sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
);
```

Comment: to other users that can't see any sorting arrows in the BE yet: make sure the field 'sorting' is in your table

Comment: ... and defined in the `ctrl` part of the TCA.